# Identify random input characters among the certain numerical format in Python df

Tags: python, pandas

I had to clean the column with membership_id, however, there are lots of random input values like '0000000', '99999', '*', 'na'.

The membership_id is serial numbers. The format of member ID is ranged from 4 digits to 12 digits, in which:

4 digits - 9 digits are starting from any non-zero number, while from 10 to 12 digits are starting from 1000xxxxxxxx.

Sorry for not describing the format clearly at beginning, I just found the IDs failed to meet this criteria is an invalid one. I would like to distinguish all of these non-membership id format as 0, thanks for help.

```
         member_id
 1      176828287         
 2      176841791         
 3      202142958         
 4      222539874         
 5      223565464         
 6      224721631         
 7      227675081         
 8      30235355118       
 9        %                  
10      ---                
11      .                  
12      .215694985         
13      0                  
14      00                 
15      000                
16      00000000000000     
17      99999999999999     
18      999999999999999    
19      : 211066980        
20      D5146159           
21      JulieGreen         
22      N/a                
23      NONE               
24      None               
25      PP - Premium Pr    
26      T0000              
27      T0000019           
28      T0000022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, uses **regex expression** = `\A((1000\d{8})|([1-9]\d{3,10}))\Z` will meet your requirements.

Above regex expression matches below:

1. 12 digits beginning with `1000`
2. 4 to 11 digits and must be beginning with `1`

Below is **one demo**:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(['176828287','176841791','202142958','222539874','223565464','224721631','227675081','30235355118',
  '%','---','.','.215694985','0','00','000','00000000000000','99999999999999','999999999999999',':211066980',
  'D5146159','JulieGreen','N/a','NONE','None','PP - PremiumPr','T0000','T0000019','T0000022'], columns=['member_id'])

r = re.compile(r'\A((1000\d{8})|([1-9]\d{3,10}))\Z')
df['valid'] = df['member_id'].apply(lambda x: bool(r.match(x)))
#you can use df['member_id'] = df['member_id'].apply(lambda x: x if bool(r.match(x)) else 0) to replace invalid id with 0
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
          member_id  valid
0         176828287   True
1         176841791   True
2         202142958   True
3         222539874   True
4         223565464   True
5         224721631   True
6         227675081   True
7       30235355118   True
8                 %  False
9               ---  False
10                .  False
11       .215694985  False
12                0  False
13               00  False
14              000  False
15   00000000000000  False
16   99999999999999  False
17  999999999999999  False
18       :211066980  False
19         D5146159  False
20       JulieGreen  False
21              N/a  False
22             NONE  False
23             None  False
24   PP - PremiumPr  False
25            T0000  False
26         T0000019  False
27         T0000022  False
```

Comment: Strange - this pattern does not meet the requirements. Tbh i don't understand the acception.

Comment: @SpghttCd because the OP said `30235355118` is a valid ID, probably it didn't describe the criteria very well especially for this rule=`while from 10 to 12 digits are starting from 1000xxxxxxxx`. But the approach will be same, just need to tune the regex expression for the criteria a little bit.

Comment: However, shouldn't you at least update it, so that the re-pattern matches OPs latest requirements? They're in my impression not an re-expert(besides that: "New Contributor"), so perhaps not able or at least not enough aware of the details to apply the little corrections.

Comment: @SpghttCd lol, but I saw OP @ you then said it did meet the requirements, though the OP deleted that comment later, and added one comment to your answer. That is why I said probably OP did not describe its criteria correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a regex already made that satisfies the criteria for the data you want to replace with 0? If not, you have to either have to create one, or make a dictionary `terms = {'N/a':0, '---':0}` of the individual items you want to replace and then call [.map(terms)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) on the series.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` has built-in string functions, which include pattern matching algorithms.
So you can easily create a boolean mask, which distinguishes valid from invalid id's:

```
pattern = r'1000\d{6,8}$|[1-9]\d{3,8}$'
mask = df.member_id.str.match(pattern)
```

To print only the valid rows, just use the mask as index:

```
print(df[mask])

    member_id
1  176828287                                                
2  176841791                                                
3  202142958                                                
4  222539874                                                
5  223565464                                                
6  224721631                                                
7  227675081
```

To set invalid data to `0`, just use the complement of the mask:

```
df.loc[~mask] = 0
print(df)

    member_id                                               
1   176828287                                               
2   176841791                                              
3   202142958                                               
4   222539874                                               
5   223565464                                             
6   224721631                                               
7   227675081                                             
8           0                                             
9           0                                           
10          0                                            
11          0                                             
12          0
13          0
14          0
15          0
16          0
17          0
18          0
19          0
20          0
21          0
22          0
23          0
24          0
25          0
26          0
27          0
28          0
```

Comment: Sorry for my editing the descriptions. Since there is no clear criteria, I just figured it out from the existing dataset. I'm new here, sorry for confusion. :)

Comment: I understand that - and don't get me wrong, you can choose whatever solution you like best (although of course I naturally find my solution cleaner than that of @Sphinx and I can imagine that it's even more efficient, but this is not proven yet). However, both solutions _can_ work, but for both it's crucial that the regular expression pattern _exactly_ meets your requirements. Otherwise you'll end up getting wrongly deleted id's and false positives.